# Pandoc with Emoji and Pictographs

Tags: unicode, fonts, emoji, pandoc, xelatex

Is there a way to get a PDF from a Markdown file which contains unicode, emoji and pictographs ?

I'm running this test:

```
echo ':smile: → ★   ⚠️' | pandoc -f markdown+emoji --latex-engine=xelatex -o foo.pdf
```

With all my system fonts.

Best result I got so far was with:

- [DejaVu Sans](https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/) font:

  [image]
- [NotoEmoji Nerd Font](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/tree/master/patched-fonts/Noto/Emoji):

  [image]

I've tried some different pandoc input format (`-f / --from`) and latex engine without success. Is there a perfect font out there or any recommendations on how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 7):

A few days ago I was looking for a solution for this exact problem,
but couldn't find any... so I developed my own solution:
a [Pandoc filter to include emojis in the generated PDF](https://github.com/masbicudo/Pandoc-Emojis-Filter).

There are some compromises and limitations though:

- I had to use a `template.tex` file, so if you already use a template, you'll have to merge pieces from my template with yours. That could be a real pain... but I flagged the changes that I made to the original `template.tex` generated by Pandoc. At least this can help a little.
- I have no experience with `Lua` language to make a filter. So I tried `Python`, and it didn't work as I expected, because I couldn't find a library to translate the unicode emoji code-points to something I could work with. Finally, I made it using `Javascript`, so `NodeJS` is required. Also, some NPM packages must be installed.
- I used `InkScape` to convert SVG from online sources, to PDF, so that they could be inserted into the PDF. This is necessary because LaTeX was not recognizing the SVG image format.
- At this moment, I didn't have time yet to implement an automatic install of the filter.
  Checkout the Git repository, and use it from there... it's the best advice I can give. There is a an example script to convert the [`readme.md`](https://github.com/masbicudo/Pandoc-Emojis-Filter/blob/master/readme.md) to pdf. I also committed the [resulting PDF](https://github.com/masbicudo/Pandoc-Emojis-Filter/blob/master/example.pdf).
- I don't know if it will work with `xelatex` or `lualatex` or anything othar than `pdflatex`, because I only had time to test it using the default engine for Pandoc, that is `pdflatex`.

### Using the Emoji filter

Prerequisites: `Pandoc` and `NodeJS`

1. Checkout the repository
2. Install NPM packages that are needed:

   ```
   npm install
   ```
3. Run Pandoc, passing the filter, the template, the correct input format, the emoji source, and so on. The following is the command used to compile the example.pdf from the readme.md:

   ```
   pandoc --template="template.tex" -o example.pdf readme.md \
       --filter=emoji_filter.js -M emoji=noto-emoji --from gfm \
       -V links-as-notes=true -V colorlinks -V urlcolor=NavyBlue
   ```

   - `--template="template.tex"` indicate the template.tex file present in the repository
   - `-o example.pdf` represents the output filename
   - `readme.md` is the input filename
   - `--filter=emoji_filter.js` indicate the emoji filter script filename
   - `-M emoji=noto-emoji` is a metadata parameter that the emoji filter reads to know what kind of emoji you want. There are two options at this moment: `noto-emoji` and `twemoji`. You can see a [full emoji list at unicode.org](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html).

     - `noto-emoji`: refers to the [Noto Color Emojis by Google](https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/emoji/)
     - `twemoji`: refers to the [Twemoji by Twitter](https://twemoji.twitter.com/)
   - `--from gfm` is the input format, gfm means GitHub Flavored Markdown. I use it because it can convert emojis in the format `:__name__:` to unicode code-points, that my filter can recognize.
   - the other parameters are not meaningful for this answer... they are used to adjust how links appear in the final PDF.

I hope this answer, and the emoji filter will help!
Any further question, please ask in the comment...
maybe if you think that I should post and explain some parts of the code.
I really don't know what parts could be helpful in a concise answer
since the code is quite complicated.

Anyway, feel free to ask =)

Comment: This does seem to be a nice solution @Miguel Angelo!

I just cloned into your repository and executed your example and it results in:

    `/usr/bin/env: ‘node\r’: No such file or directory
    Error running filter emoji_filter.js:
    Filter returned error status 127`

My environment is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, NodeJs v14.18.1, pandoc 2.5, inkscape 0.92.5 and TexLive 2021 (hope I didn't miss anything here).

Can you tell me what my problem is?

Answer (score 2):

I know is an old ask, but I've had too painful time with pdf converter.
For the emojis I use `pandoc` to convert `markdown` in `html` and [twemoji](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji) to convert emoji in svg with this metadata.yml:

```yaml
header-includes: |
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/v/latest/twemoji.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready
        (
          function()
          {
                twemoji.parse(document.body);
          }
        );
    </script>
```

And in css

```css
.emoji {                
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;           
  height: 1em;          
  vertical-align: -.1em;
}
```

build the html:

```sh
pandoc -s my_doc.md  -o my_doc.html --metadata-file metadata.yml --from markdown+emoji
```

After that I use chromium to make my pdf with

```sh
chromium --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=my_doc.pdf my_doc.html --print-to-pdf-no-header
```

But can work with pandoc html to pdf, just a better engine for javascript to me.

This is the smarter and simplest way I fine to deal with emojis, pdf and markdown.